# Where to ask PBS/Torque Configuration question?

Tags: pbs, torque

I've noticed that several questions on SO about PBS have gone unanswered.  Is there a more appropriate forum to ask these questions? For example:

[PBS programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366521)

[How to limit number of concurrently running PBS jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053281)

[Submitting multiple jobs TORQUE/PBS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504262)

**My Real Question:** I am having a problem with my PBS configuration. I have a single computer which I've setup torque so that I can submit hundreds of jobs and don't have to babysit it.  But I've somehow messed up the configuration because I have submitted three jobs which should require a total of four cpus:

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=2
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
```

And all three are running right now! Even though I've set:

resources_max.ncpus = 3

for the queue -- because I've got a quad-core and I want to save one processor for the OS.  In the qmgr, it also reports:

resources_assigned.ncpus = 3

What is going on?!? Clearly I've bolluxed up something.  Is this the appropriate forum?  Should I be asking over on Unix/Linux? or Ubuntu (which is my OS)?

Comment: I discovered my problem.  In my nodes file, I had `myserver np=4`, which torque was using instead of reading `resources_max.ncpus = 3`.  I'll still award points/answer if I should be asking this question elsewhere.

Comment: The custodians of torque, Adaptive Computing; has an overflow style page on their website. It is currently in beta. http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/questions/  You can also sign up for the torque user groups http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/support/download-center/torque-download/mailing-lists/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ask about configuring PBS at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com);
2. Ask about using PBS for your tasks here;
3. This question should have been asked at [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).